# How to select from JSON field in MySQL 5.6 where json_extract is not available?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

If my row has a `varchar` with the following value: "`[1,2,3]`", how could I select the whole row if I need the value to contain one of the numbers (a 2 or a 3)?

Comment: You could use a regular expression. But the best solution would be to normalize your table design so you don't have values like that in the first place.

Comment: Checkout my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816269/how-to-get-values-from-mysql5-6-column-if-that-contains-json-document-as-strin/#answer-69127222). It will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, you're using MySQL 5.6, so the `JSON_EXTRACT()` function is not available.

The only options I would recommend are:

1. Upgrade to MySQL 5.7 or later
2. Fetch the whole JSON document into an application and use a JSON decoding function.

You could also try to parse JSON using other [string functions available in MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html), but it'll be awkward and time-consuming to develop.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that `json_extract` is not available (hence the title). I was looking more for a `like '%2%'` equivalent (or a proper regex) to help me match the row.

Comment: I would not willingly choose to use a regex to parse out specific fields from JSON. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the function in the sql

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `json_extract_c`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `json_extract_c`(
 details TEXT,
 required_field VARCHAR (255)
) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
SET details = SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, "{", -1);
SET details = SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, "}", 1);
RETURN TRIM(
BOTH '"' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            details,
            CONCAT(
                '"',
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(required_field,'$.', - 1),
                '":'
            ),
            - 1
        ),
        ',"',
        1
    ),
    ':',
    -1
  )
) ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because i needed a JSON_EXTRACT on mysql 5.6 i wrote it by myself a copy of original function that can extract values like the native function in mysql 5.7

[Link to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55690616/11363483)