# custom json_extract function for mysql 5.6 not working as expected

Tags: mysql, json

I am on mysql 5.6 so using custom function to extraxt json field. It's working fine if there is single value for each json field but failing if there are multiple.

```
Table extract
user_id,    cb_contactgroup
289,    [{"cb_mobile":"777777777","cb_phonefixedline":"666666666"}]
290,    [{"cb_mobile":"999999999","cb_phonefixedline":"888888888"}]
291,    [{"cb_mobile":"1111111111","cb_phonefixedline":"2222222222"},{"cb_mobile":"3333333333","cb_phonefixedline":"4444444444"}]
```

For `user_id 291` there should be two lines but only one line showing as below.

```
user_id, mobile,    phonefixedline
289,    777777777,  666666666
290,    999999999,  888888888
291,    3333333333, 4444444444
```

I am using following function. I am not a technical, could someone help me to correct following function:

```
ELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `json_extract_c`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `json_extract_c`(
  details TEXT,
  required_field VARCHAR (255)
) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  RETURN TRIM(
    BOTH '"' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          details,
          CONCAT(
            '"',
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(required_field,'$.', - 1),
            '"'
          ),
          - 1
        ),
        '",',
        1
      ),
      ':',
      - 1
    )
  ) ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Post from where the query has been picked
[How to get values from MySQL(5.6) column if that contains json document as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816269/how-to-get-values-from-mysql5-6-column-if-that-contains-json-document-as-strin) - `@user3631341`

Comment: not a single suggestion yet on this  :(

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816269/how-to-get-values-from-mysql5-6-column-if-that-contains-json-document-as-strin/#answer-69127222) is will help you..

Answer (score 1):

Because i needed a JSON_EXTRACT on mysql 5.6 i wrote it by myself a copy of original function that can extract values like the native function in mysql 5.7

[Link to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55690616/11363483)