# How to replace keys of a JSON values in a column using the values of another column in a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have two tables in mysql schema, let's call them `sites` and `fields`. The sites table as the following schema:

```
create table if not exists sites
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    collection_id int null,
    name varchar(255) null,
    properties text null,
)
;
```

And the fields has the following schema

```
create table fields
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    collection_id int null, 
    name varchar(255) null,
    code varchar(255) null,
)
;
```

The two tables can be joined on the `collection_id` column. The `sites` table stores json data in the properties column with **the keys of the json objects being values of id column in field table.** For example, here is a sample json that can be found in the properties column

`{"1281":"Type A","1277":4}`

The keys in the json above are the ids of a record in the fields.

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+
|id       |  name        |   code       |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1277    |  Years       |  Yr          |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1281    | Type         |  Ty          |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Now, I want to output properties json where the keys are replaced by the names of the field instead of the id values. Using the above example the output should look like:

`{"Type": "Type A", "Years": 4}`

I have tried the following so far

```
select JSON_OBJECT(fd.name, JSON_EXTRACT(st.properties, concat('$."', fd.id, '"'))) as prop  
from sites as st join fields as fd on fd.collection_id = st.collection_id where st.collection_id = 145 and

JSON_EXTRACT(st.properties, concat('$."', fd.id, '"')) is not  null ;
```

However, this produces json object for each field instead of site.

It outputs something like below:

```
 +----------------------------+
 |        prop                |
+-----------------------------+
 |  {"Type": "Type A"}        |
 |                            |
 +----------------------------+
 |   {"Type": "Type B"}       |
 |                            |
 +-----------------------------+
 |                            |
 |    {"Year": 4}             |
 |                            |
 +----------------------------+
```

How can modify the above code to get desired output? Or Is there a better solution?

Comment: Generally, there is not a good reason to store complex fields in a JSON.  There are exceptions, but this in generally an anti-pattern.  Can you not break this out into fields so this is a standard query?   If you must store this as JSON, perhaps the JSON datatype will serve you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I arrived at the solution using the [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to concatenate the results for each site into one after I have grouped them by site id. Here is the query:

```
select concat('{' ,group_concat(concat('\"', cast(fd.code as char(50)), '\":' , JSON_EXTRACT(st.properties, concat('$.\"', fd.id, '\"')))), '}') as prop , st.id as site 
from sites as st join fields as fd on fd.collection_id = st.collection_id 
where st.collection_id = 145 and
JSON_EXTRACT(st.properties, concat('$."', fd.id, '"')) is not  null
group by st.id
```

**Note:** This solution assumes you are on MySQL version 5.7+ as that's when `JSON_EXTRACT` function was introduced. If you are on a lower version, use the UDF in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089335/3380414) as a replacement for `JSON_EXTRACT`.