# syntax error or access viloation 1305 dbName.Json_contains does not exist

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

i am using laravel for my project. i performed a query. it works fine in localhost. but started giving this error after i have uploaded it on the server. here is my query below

```
$result = Card::SELECT('id','name','unique_id','nid','geo_union_id','house_category','house_name','vata_list','mobile','profession','family_members')
    ->whereraw("JSON_CONTAINS(vata_list,'[$request->id]')")
    ->where('geo_union_id','=',$union)
            ->get();
```

and this is the error i am having in live server

Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION mydb.JSON_CONTAINS does not exist

Comment: Check the MySQL version con your server

Comment: MySQL 5.7 has been GA since 2015-10-21. If you need JSON functions, you should just upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that MySQL version in your local and server are the same.
Since json_contains was introduced in later versions of MySQL (5.7 think so).

Comment: yeah. mine is less than 5.7. Does it have an alternative function?

Comment: You need to write a custom function in that case. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816269/how-to-get-values-from-mysql5-6-column-if-that-contains-json-document-as-strin

Comment: json extract in that example could be possible if i had jsob objects, but in this case i have arrays [1,3,7]

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is you are calling `whereraw()`, instead you need to be calling `whereRaw()` (notice the uppercase R).